# Automatically turn work profile off on evenings and week-ends

Tags: applications, settings, profiles, android-10

I'd like to block myself from accessing my work apps at certain times and days (typically, evenings and weekends). Ideally, I'd like to use the system-level setting to remove access to all apps on the work profile. Back when all my apps (personal & corporate) were living on the same profile, I used the paid version of [Stay Focused](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stayfocused) to block all work apps individually, and that was a satisfactory solution. Unfortunately, now the "device policy" forces me to put all work apps on the work profile, this Stay Focused app isn't available on the work profile version of the Play Store, and when I install it on the personal profile, it can't block apps on the work profile, so it's basically useless.

I know turning work profile on/off manually is really easy, but

1. I too easily forget to do so (and then mindlessly check work email late at night), and
2. the fact that it's so easy to turn it back on is part of the problem (ideally, I need to be 3-4 clicks away from accessing anything work-related, otherwise I do it mindlessly).

I use a Pixel 3A on Android 10. I can't root my phone. Is there a workaround or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 5):

If you go to settings > digital wellbeing + parental controls > digital wellbeing > ways to disconnect
There's a setting for setting a work profile schedule

Comment: Ah thanks… I don't use work profile anymore, so I can't verify your answer. If someone independently confirms that it works for them, I'll accept it.

Comment: It does work as Greta says. I just added it to mine. When it asks you to select "Personal" or "Work" select personal and then the work schedule is there under "ways to disconnect".

Comment: It's very well documented here https://www.xda-developers.com/pause-work-profile-schedule/